# Why is tcolorbox preventing noindentafter from working properly?

Tags: spacing, packages, indentation, debugging

I  just discovered  that  the  `tcolorbox` package  prevents
`noindentafter` from doing its job:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{noindentafter}
\NoIndentAfterEnv{verbatim}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent Text.

\begin{verbatim}
code
\end{verbatim}

Text.
  
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Indentation test]

Removing line 4 (the  `\usepackage` of `tcolorbox`) makes it
work properly. Is there any way to use them simultaneously?

Comment: It's because `tcolorbox` loads `verbatim`, I think, which redefines the `verbatim` environment ....